# Improve Java LinkList implementation

Tags: java

As mentioned moved to code review:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162021/improving-java-linklist-implementation

Comment: Please post this on [codereview.se].

Comment: Thanks I will move the question to Code Review

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for review of working code belongs on codereview.SE com

Comment: @user340 Don't move. Open your question, select all/ copy ... and then delete it. Paste a new one on the other site. Dont leave such stuff around here. That just means that people will waste their time looking into your question here.

Comment: First suggested improvement: improve indentation.

Comment: @GhostCat I hope I have done it correctly?

Comment: What I mean is: we dont keep links to other sites here. The correct move  is to **delete** your question here; now that you asked another one elsewhere!

Comment: Forum recommends not to delete questions with answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into **generics**. (google it - this is too much to explain here)

Then at some points you use an extra Object for `oneBeforeLast`.
You could try something like this instead:

```
public void deleteLast(){
    if(!isEmpty()){
        Node tmp = first;
        while (tmp.next != null && tmp.next.next != null){
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
        tmp.next = null;
    }
}
```

Another point is: do you ever use the `last` variable? I don't think so and in singly linked lists there is no great use for it. (The only reason to have this might be to create a method `getLast()`.)

And please try to keep code samples shorter by avoiding empty lines and such large main methods ;)

Comment: Thanks, @goerlibe for the suggestions. Yes, last is not being used here..